# Function whose derivative is not continuous

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f$ be a differtiable  function on $[a,b]$ and $f'(x)$ is not continous  at some $C$ in $(a,b)$, then
Either left limit or right limit of $f'(x)$  at $C$ does not exist????

True or false
I know that $f'(x)$ don't have jump Discontinuities.So I think it is true.but not sure

Comment: You already know the answer. Just think of the contrapositive.

Comment: @SangchulLee Please consider that I am not very knowledgeable in this area.  Why can't both limits exist, but simply be different?

Comment: Both limits can't exist and be different, because that is a jump discontinuity (the definition of jump discontinuity is that both left and right limits exist and be unequal), and by what you know $f'$ doesn't have one. So if $f'$ is discontinuous, it must happen that one of the limits does not exist.

Comment: @Teresa Lundin ,But it might be case that leftdand right  limit of f'(x) both exist at c and equal but these limit not equal to f(c)

Comment: @user423255 Oh, yes, I get what you are trying to say. As it turns out, even this is not possible. For a stronger statement : one can show that $f'$ has the intermediate value property. This means that between two points $a$ and $b$, $f'$ will have to take every value between $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$. By using this result on smaller and smaller intervals around the point $c$, you can show that if the limits both exist , then they must be equal to $f'(c)$, then continuity follows.

Comment: Functions with the intermediate value property are called *Darboux* functions, and one can show that Darboux functions admit only essential discontinuities i.e. where either LH or RH limit doesn't exist. For any differentiable function $f$, the function $f'$ is Darboux.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @user2661923 You are welcome.